# "Echo is OFF" text always inserted into batch file when SET variable is written to a batch file IF the file is made by another batch program

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, text-files, echo

I am trying to create a batch file using another batch program using:

`@echo {code here}>>batch-program.bat`, but whenever I try to write code to write the contents of a SET variable to a text file, the batch program does not write the code into the other batch file, but instead writes "Echo is OFF."

Code is here:

```
@echo off
@echo @echo off>>apt.bat
@echo color 2A>>apt.bat
@echo echo example-batch>>apt.bat
@echo cd C:/Users/Default/apt/assets>>apt.bat
@echo mkdir cmdInput>>apt.bat
@echo cd C:/Users/Default/apt/assets/cmdInput>>apt.bat
@echo set /p cmdInput= cmd->>apt.bat
@echo %cmdInput%>>used-cmdInput.txt>>apt.bat
@echo pause>>apt.bat
```

This *should* have created a batch file named apt.bat, and written into the batch file:

```
@echo off
echo color 2A
echo example-batch
cd C:/Users/Default/apt/assets
mkdir cmdInput
cd C:/Users/Default/apt/assets/cmdInput
set /p cmdInput= cmd-
%cmdInput%>>used-cmdInput.txt
pause
```

but the 9th line (`%cmdInput%>>used-cmdInput.txt`)
is instead converted into the text line "Echo is OFF".

Have I done anything wrong, or is it just a really weird bug?

EDIT: I found another problem in the program, that because `mkdir cmdInput` is always run when `apt.bat` is run, so it displays a error message because of `apt.bat` trying to create the directory `cmdInput` though it already exists. apt/assets. So I *have* changed the code a bit, so that the directory `cmdInput` is created in the first "creation" batch file (the program that was used to create apt.bat). `mkdir cmdInput` has been removed from `apt.bat`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape <kbd>></kbd> with <kbd>^</kbd> but you need to escape <kbd>%</kbd> with <kbd>%</kbd>

```
@echo %%cmdInput%%^>^>used-cmdInput.txt>>apt.bat
```

unless you want to output the **contents** of `cmdinput` where you need

```
@echo %cmdInput%^>^>used-cmdInput.txt>>apt.bat
```

You can add `2>nul` to the end of a `md` command to suppress the error message generated if the directory already exists.

You should use backslashes <kbd>\</kbd> in directorynames, not forward slashes <kbd>/</kbd>. In winbat, the forward slash is often used for command switches. *Sometimes* forward slashes will work for directorynames, but backslashes always work.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to "escape" the percent-signs with another `%` and other special chars like `>` with a caret) to prevent evaluation of your variable `%cmdInput%` (which probably is empty - therefore the `Echo is off`).

Also a single `@echo off` is sufficient. No need to add a `@` to every line.

```
@echo off
echo @echo off>>apt.bat
echo color 2A>>apt.bat
echo echo example-batch>>apt.bat
echo cd C:/Users/Default/apt/assets>>apt.bat
echo mkdir cmdInput>>apt.bat
echo cd C:/Users/Default/apt/assets/cmdInput>>apt.bat
echo set /p cmdInput= cmd->>apt.bat
echo %%cmdInput%%^>^>used-cmdInput.txt>>apt.bat
echo pause>>apt.bat
```

A more elegant way is to use only a single redirection (`cmd`has to open the file for writing just once):

```
@echo off
(
echo @echo off
echo color 2A
echo echo example-batch
echo cd C:/Users/Default/apt/assets
echo mkdir cmdInput
echo cd C:/Users/Default/apt/assets/cmdInput
echo set /p cmdInput= cmd-
echo %%cmdInput%%^>^>used-cmdInput.txt
echo pause
)>apt.bat
```

Comment: thanks for the `echo` tip, but now the `Echo is OFF` is replaced by `^`

Comment: In batch scripts you need to escape `%` like `%%`; the `^%` only works in command prompt...